# Which one should I use for my website:Dynamic LInks vs Static links?

Tags: html, web, hyperlink

I am building a website for the first time. The website is regarding sports books and movies where people can get info about these books and movies and also write their reviews and all that stuffs.

Now, I am not really sure that whether to use dynamic or static links for this website! At the time of release, my website will have info about 700 books(which means I will have to build 700 pages manually if I use static linking) which is expected to grow with time. But I read it here: http://www.seositecheckup.com/articles/21>  that  **dynamic links are not most suited for SEO** .

What would you prefer? Building 700 pages individually(**STATIC LINKING**) and build just one template page and let it talk to the database(**DYNAMIC LINKING**)?

PS: Most of the sites I see around have static links.

Comment: Do you ***really*** want to spend the effort of making and maintaining 700 individual pages?

Comment: @Kolink I can.. to make my website work.!! ANd most of the sites I see on the web work on static links.

Comment: No they don't. They use things like .htaccess to make dynamic pages look like static resources.

Comment: @Kolink Is that a good idea? I read this too too that 'making dynamic links static would only do harm to you'

Comment: Ultimately, SEO isn't something I worry about. I get much, much more business from direct advertising and word-of-mouth than any search engine ever gave me. After that my page rank went up and search engines found me anyway. That said, since I make games there's only a limited range that can be accessed by a search bot.

Comment: @Kolink I will go for dynamic links then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic Linking (as you call it is)

using a DB and a single template - is very good interms of maintainability and Extensibility.

You reduce the time of re-designing or changing links when they are dynamic.

Dynamic links are actually SEO friendly - you can add a description to the link that can help in the indexing.

Comment: But   then why most of the sites including work of Static Linking?

Comment: I would say - that's because they are small with 10-15 pages and The one who designed them doesn't know programming. :)

Comment: Small Sites? NO!! bookboon.com/ do you think this is a small site?

Comment: Do you think they are Static? Please revisit your idea of Static comments. They look Dynamic ex: http://bookboon.com/en/organization-ebooks  - the "en" - could be a value for a parameter (truly Language) and "organization-ebooks" could be a value for another parameter.

Comment: I would follow what you say. Finally, I should go for dynamic linking then? And should I make those dynamic links like static links(like the website above) or let them be pure dynamic links?

Comment: Making them look like Dynamic Links - helps to make sure Search engines identify you easy with the text in the links rather than the code. This also helps you hide the technology used behind.

Comment: Cool!! I will use this thing only. Thanks